# Entity Framework, загрузка сущности, которая уже есть в контексте

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Изучаю Entity Framework. Есть приложение WPF, взаимодействует непосредственно с БД с помощью этого ORM. В приложении есть справочники. Принцип работы со справочником следующий. При загрузки данных из базы, создается репозиторий справочника, который является оберткой над DbContext. Т.е. DbContext живет все время пока открыт справочник или пока не выполнена команда обновления справочника. Если в каком-то участке кода справочника (выполнение какой-то команды по элементу) я выполняю загрузку, например, некоторой уже первоначально загруженной в справочник (т.е. в контекст) сущности по id или коду, что в конечном счете сводится к простому запросу вида:

```
var entity = Context.Set<Entity>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == "Code1");
```

то запрос уходит в базу, но так как сущность уже существует в контексте, в entity оказывается первоначальный объект (первоначально загруженный при открытии справочника), не из базы. Если этот объект был изменен в другом клиенте или из любых других источников, эти изменения не отображаются в переменной entity. Действительную перезагрузку объекта из БД, я так понимаю, можно сделать только с помощью

```
this.Context.Entry(entity).Reload();
```

но в API репозитория доступа к Context.Entry нет. К тому же, есть необходимость выполнять произвольные, более сложные linq запросы со связанными сущностями. А не просто извлечь элемент из БД по коду.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то заставить Entity Framework в описанной выше ситуации перезаписывать сущности из базы при произвольных linq запросах не пересоздавая контекст?

Comment: а какие у вас проблемы с пересоздаванием контекста?

Comment: Архитектура приложения такова, что он создается для всего справочника при старте и живет все время, пока справочник открыт. Пересоздается только по команде обновить. Все взаимодействия с данными осуществляются через него. Пользователь вносит изменения в справочник (сущностные объекты), они отслеживаются контекстом, по команде сохранить выполняется SaveChanges(), генерируются команды (update, insert, delete). И контекст дальше продолжает жить. До следующего обновления или сохранения изменений. Т.е. реализуется Unit Of Work. Изменить такой подход в настоящее время не представляется возможным.

Comment: Если у вас контекст висит в памяти всё время, то тут совсем не `Unit Of Work`, а что то другое.

Comment: [Invalidating/Disabling Entity Framework cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35545313/312041)

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что все изменения пользователя за раз фиксируется в БД, в транзакции, при сохранении.

Comment: AsNoTracking() тоже не подойдет, потому что требуется отслеживание

Comment: Как вы предполагаете отслеживание с отсутсвием кеша совместить? Раз нельзя пересоздать контекст, вы можете пересоздать справочник для тех запросов, которые просто должны вернуть свежие данные

Comment: Я предполагал, что если из БД загружу объекты, которые уже есть в контексте, то они будут заменены на новые, в статусе - неизмененный (что-то по типу this.Context.Entry(entity).Reload(), но для всей выборки). Но, видимо, EF в этом случае новые значения из БД не берет, а использует то, что уже загружено ранее.

Comment: я не очень разбираюсь в кеше EF, я с БД не работаю вообще, но, мне кажется, у вас явно проблема с вашим справочником, если он у вас одновременно и доступ даёт к БД и кешем занимается и вы этим управлять не можете. Я бы начал решать эту проблему, и создавал бы контекст только когда он нужен, а не держал бы его в памяти

Comment: В принципе, эта стать рассказывает про проблемы кеша в EF - [ссылка](http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/). Например, в 3-ем пунтке говорится о желаемом поведении из предыдущего моего комментария с помощью опции MergeOption. А вообще, как я понимаю, в каждой конкретной ситуации нужно рассматривать какое-то индивидуальное решение. А по умолчанию EF использует кэш.

Comment: Да, поэтому я когда работал с бд, создавал контекст только когда мне уже надо было непосредственно работать с бд и не держал его в памяти

Comment: По поводу проблемы со справочником, я все же так не думаю.Тот же Microsoft для WPF и WinForms рекомендует использовать один экземпляр контекста на всю форма. По повоуд "если он у вас одновременно и доступ даёт к БД и кешем занимается" не понял что Вы имеете ввиду. Просто за справочником висит контекст, который отслеживает все изменения внесенные пользователем и отправляет команды в БД. Просто хотелось бы, чтобы данные в контексте всегда точно соответствовали данным в БД. Но оказывается еще нужно учитывать кэш в некоторых отдельных ситуациях.

Comment: `Microsoft для WPF и WinForms рекомендует использовать один экземпляр контекста на всю форма` это где такое, дайте ссылочку почитать

Comment: [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext)

Comment: Ага, спасибо, почитаю

Comment: Как раз таки, данный подход и позволяет использовать преимущества механизма отслеживания в EF.

Comment: Почитал, по прежнему не нравится идея держать контекст. Он не потокобезопасен, плюс идет привязка к конкретной технологии. Мне больше нравится иметь возможность заменить контекст на другую орм или вообще на другую бд. Потому я в своем домашнем проекте написал кеш сам и сам контролирую, когда кеш работает, а когда живые данные.

Comment: Хорошо, на вкус и цвет, как говорится.

Comment: Ну я пишу по свой случай, конечно. Как в вашем случае да, вы меня убедили, раз мс рекомендует контекст на окно, может это и имеет смысл, потому сказать не могу ничего теперь :)

Comment: Всегда держать контекст - плохая идея, обсуждалось это 100500 раз. Поднимайте контекст по запросу пользователя и будет счастье.

Comment: В рамках существующего контекста в голову приходит только Reload перед запросом или EntityState.Detached после запроса, но неясно зачем.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94896/discussion-on-question-by-deol-entity-framework----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь [ссылка](http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/) представлена необходимая информация по теме. Спасибо [tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763/tym32167) за переадресацию на вопрос, из ответа на который взят данный источник.

Если в каких-то случаях необходимо выполнять запросы, которые будут полностью обновлять уже загруженные в контекст сущности данными из БД, то можно поступить следующим образом. Пусть есть некоторая обертка над DbContext - BaseRepository. Выписал два свойства - All и All2. Первое свойство All определяет поведение по умолчанию. Можно конструировать различные linq запросы. При загрузке данных из БД будет проверяться есть ли уже в контексте сущность. Если она есть, то используется она, новая игнорируется. Если же использовать свойство All2, то поведение будет противоположное. Если в контексте сущность уже существует, она будет перезаписана новой из БД.

```
 public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
        where TEntity  : class, IEntity<TKey>
{            
        private readonly DbContext _context;

        protected DbContext Context => this._context;

        // ...

        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> All
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Context.Set<TEntity>();
            }
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> All2
        {
            get
            {
                var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Context).ObjectContext;
                var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
                objectSet.MergeOption = System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;

                return objectSet;
            }
        }

        // ...
}
```